# как сделать чтобы бот отправлял информацию при нажатии inline кнопок

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Всем привет, копаюсь с ботом и не могу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии пользователем на inline кнопку, ботом отправлялась  информация

начальные кнопки:

```
btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("СПИД", callback_data='spid')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Рак", callback_data='rak')
        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Грипп", callback_data='gripp')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn4)
        
        # Отправляем сообщение с клавиатурой
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите болезнь", reply_markup=markup)
```

при нажатии на одну их них появляются другие inline кнопки, но уже с лекарствами:

```
if text == 'спид':
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Тенофовир", callback_data='tenofovir')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Эмтрицитабин", callback_data='emtricitabin')
            btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Долутегравир", callback_data='dolutegravir')
        elif text == 'рак':
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Химиотерапия", callback_data='himioterapiya')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Лучевая терапия", callback_data='luchevaya_terapiya')
            btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Иммунотерапия", callback_data='immunoterapiya')
        elif text == 'грипп':
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Осельтамивир", callback_data='oseltamivir')
            btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Занамивир", callback_data='zanamivir')
            btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Перамивир", callback_data='peramivir')
```

как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на встроенные кнопки( лекарства) выводилась краткая информация о них.
пробовал сделать:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_callback_query(call):
    if call.data == 'tenofovir':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Тенофовир - применяется для лечения ВИЧ-инфекции. Способ применения: принимать по 1 таблетке в день. Побочные эффекты могут включать диарею, тошноту и головную боль.")
    elif call.data == 'emtricitabin':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Эмтрицитабин - используется для лечения ВИЧ-инфекции. Способ применения: принимать по 1 таблетке в день. Побочные эффекты могут включать усталость, головную боль и тошноту.")
    elif call.data == 'dolutegravir':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Долутегравир - применяется для лечения ВИЧ-инфекции. Способ применения: принимать по 1 таблетке в день. Побочные эффекты могут включать головную боль, тошноту и бессонницу.")
```

как итог, бот не отправляет информацию об лекарствах.